# how to write xpath for div and strong in html

Tags: python, xpath

I need to write xpath for div and strong

```
td[contains(div/@class,'lpadding20')//text()
```

HTML:

```
<div class="lpadding20" style="font-weight: normal;">
   <strong>Published: </strong>6/18/2019 at 11:18 AM.  This list includes 501 eligible players.
</div>
```

Comment: can u pls help me

Comment: what is your library for get this xpath things? Beautiful Soup or Scrapy or any other package? Please provide more information.

Comment: SCRAPY is the packge

Answer (score 0):

try:

```py
//div[@class="lpadding20"]//strong[contains(text(), "text you are looking for")]
```

for the precise text:

```py
//div[@class="lpadding20"]//strong[text()="text you are looking for"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `xpath` to get `strong` text.

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

htmlelem = """
<div class="lpadding20" style="font-weight: normal;">
   <strong>Published: </strong>6/18/2019 at 11:18 AM.  This list includes 501 eligible players.
</div>
"""
tree = fromstring(htmlelem)

itemstrong1 = tree.xpath("//div[@class='lpadding20']/strong/text()")[0].strip()
print(itemstrong1)
itemstrong2 = tree.xpath("//div[@class='lpadding20']/strong/following::text()")[0].strip()
print(itemstrong2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```py
from scrapy.selector import Selector

body = '<div class="lpadding20" style="font-weight: normal;"><strong>Published: </strong>6/18/2019 at 11:18 AM.  This list includes 501 eligible players.</div>'

before_strong = Selector(text=body).xpath("//div[@class='lpadding20']/strong/text()").extract_first()
after_strong = Selector(text=body).xpath("//div[@class='lpadding20']/strong/following::text()").extract_first()

print(before_strong)
print(after_strong)
```

Output:

```py
'Published: '
'6/18/2019 at 11:18 AM.  This list includes 501 eligible players.'
```